# Warning: PDO::__construct() expects parameter 4 to be array, string given in

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy empezando a programar en **PHP** y **MySql** y al tratar de conectar la base de datos con el método **PDO** me marca el error, este es mi código:

```
else {
        try {
            $conexion  = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=registro_prueba1', 'root', 'contraseña', '');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error " . $e->getMessage();
```

El error que se presenta es el siguiente:

> **Warning: PDO::__construct() expects parameter 4 to be array, string
>   given in**

¿Alguien sabe como hacerle?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que el último parámetro de la función `PDO::__construct()` recibe un arreglo de opciones de tipo `array(key=>value)` y tú le estás mandando un string vacío al poner tus dos comillas `''`.

Simplemente omítelo ya que es opcional, para que así tu función constructora quede de la siguiente forma:

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=registro_prueba1', 'root', 'contraseña');
```

Answer (score 1):

Supongo intentas realizar una conexión persistente con PDO `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT`, pero estas mandando un string vació debido a tus `' '` y ese ultimo parámetro admite solo un arreglo `array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true`

Puedes tan solo eliminar esas comillas simples `' '` luego de contraseña, quedando entonces así tu variable conexión:

`$conexion  = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=registro_prueba1', 'root', 'contraseña');`

Ya con eso conectaras de igual manera con tu base de datos